# Sum intersection of two lists in Python

Tags: python

I'm new to Python. If I have a 'data' variable like this:

```
data = [['water', 'chips', 'pie', 'fruit', 200], ['soda', 'nuts', 'cake', 'vegetables', 300], ['water', 'chips', 'cake', 'fruit', 40], ['soda', 'crackers', 'cake', 'vegetables', 80]]
```

and I have a list like this:

```
ls = [['water', 'chips'], ['soda', 'nuts']]
```

How can I return the sum of `data[i][4] for i in data` that contain both of those values and append it to the list.

```
total = 0
for i in data:
    for x in ls
        if i contains x:
             ls[2] = total += total

# should return
ls = [['water', 'chips', 240], ['soda', 'nuts', 300]]
```

The final element in `ls` is the sum of those `data[3][4]` that contain `ls[1]` *and* `ls[2]`

Comment: I am going to delete my answer, I suggest you read a tutorial as your indexing does not come close to your logic, `data[3][4]` is 80. Also x cannot contain i as x is a list. You are going to have to look at every element in x and i and compare if the interesting items can appear anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res = [
    e +  # filter list itself
    [
        sum( # sum all
            l[4]  # get fourth item if contains all
            for l in data  # take each element of data
            if all(i in l for i in e)  # check if contains all filter list
        )
    ]  # concat sum to list itself
    for e in ls  # take each element of filter list 
]
```

Comment: Is there an easy way I can find the amount of times that `all(i in l for i in e)` returns true so that I can divide it by the sum to produce the average?

Comment: @Himmel if you're using py3, just replace sum with [statistics.mean](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html?highlight=average#statistics.mean). It fails when no item in the list, you can concat `[0]` to the result list i.e. `statistics.mean([0] + [...])`. Otherwise, write your function to take avg of a list and replace `sum` with yours such that `def avg(ls): return sum(ls) / len(ls)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach: use the Counter from collections to keep track of the sum. We use the first two items in each sublist as a key, and the last item as the value:

```
from collections import Counter

data = [
    ['water', 'chips', 'pie', 'fruit', 200],
    ['soda', 'nuts', 'cake', 'vegetables', 300],
    ['water', 'chips', 'cake', 'fruit', 40],
    ['soda', 'crackers', 'cake', 'vegetables', 80]]
ls = [['water', 'chips'], ['soda', 'nuts']]

counter = Counter()
for item in data:
    if item[:2] in ls:
        counter.update({tuple(item[:2]): item[-1]})

result = [list(k) + [v] for k, v in counter.iteritems()]
print result
```

Since `Counter` behaves like a dictionary, and a dictionary does not take a list as key, we have to turn the list of the first two elements into a tuple (hence `tuple(item[:2])`).